# Column sampling with 1000 reps without replacement in r

Tags: r, sampling

Still struggling with R when it comes to writing codes from scratch. I have asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47836465/randomly-permute-columns-in-a-dataset-with-sampling-without-replacement-in-r?noredirect=1#comment82637025_47836465/%22here%22) but couldn't get an answer. I would greatly appreciate some pointers.

I have a matrix with 6 variables. I want to randomly sample from the first three columns and recalculate matching values (column 6) of the three columns and calculate the average of the 6th column. The idea is to observe the actual mean with that of 1000 reps under random sampling. Ideally i will plot the distribution of the means.

Here is my data

```
df1 = data.frame(v1 = c("Low", "Low", "High"), 
                 v2 = c("Med", "High","Low"), 
                 v3 = c("NA", "Low", "Low"),
                 ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L),
                 ID_name = c("AAA", "AA", "A"),
                 Consistency = c(1L,2L,2L))
```

From all the reading i did, looks like sample() function is good for a vector but not a matrix. I used some code, but that doesn't seem to work and i believe it is wrong. But i don't know how to take that to find a solution to my problem. Here is my code:

```
sample_size <- 3
n_rep <- 1000
s_means <- rep(NA, n_rep)

for (i in 1:n_rep){
    my_samp <- sample(df1, sample_size)
    s_means[i] <- mean(my_samp)
}

hist(s_means, breaks = 1)
abline(v = mean(df1), lty = 3)
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How would you sample 3 out of 3 columns? Or are there more than `v1-3` in your real data?

Comment: I guess you want to check to see if v1, v2 and v3 agree with each other.  If you are calculating concordance, please edit your question to state that.  Try this command: sample(df1$v1,3) on the command line.  sample(1:3,3) might also be useful depending on what you are trying to do.

Comment: There are more columns than v1-3 but i can subset those. What i am trying to find is the distribution of the concordance of v1-v3 after permuting and sampling v1-v3 about 1000 times.

Comment: You need to show a couple iterations of the calculations for how you want it to work, as what you're saying doesn't make a lot of sense. If you just want a bootstrapped mean of `Consistency`, it could be `set.seed(47); means <- replicate(1000, mean(sample(df1$Consistency, replace = TRUE))); hist(means, breaks = seq(1, 2, by = .25)); abline(v = mean(means), col = 'red')`, but I think you're after something else.

Comment: Also, `df1` is a data frame, not a matrix, which can only hold one type.

Comment: I want to sample v1-v3 without replacement, and based on each iteration, calculate the consistency, and plot the distribution of the consistency, find the mean of sampled consistency and compare that with the actual consistency of df1.  More like this:   `
sample1df= data.frame(v1 = c("Low", "High", "Low"), 
                      v2 = c("Low", "High","Med"), 
                      v3 = c("Low", "Low", "NA"))
`
`sample2df= data.frame(v1 = c("Low", "High", "Low"), 
                      v2 = c("High", "Low","Med"), 
                      v3 = c("Low", "Low", "NA")) `

Comment: Do NOT use comments to update your question. Read how to [edit]